# Frequency count in a dictionary -- Python using comprehension

Tags: python

I have a dictionary and would like to count the frequency using Python comprehension.

Example:

Input

```
{0: 'Succeeded', 1: 'Succeeded', 2: 'Failed', 3: 'Failed', 4: 'Succeeded'}
```

Output

```
{'Succeeded':3,'Failed':2}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you want to use comprehensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a comprehension, just apply a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to the `values` of your dictionary.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {0: 'Succeeded', 1: 'Succeeded', 2: 'Failed', 3: 'Failed', 4: 'Succeeded'}
>>> Counter(d.values())
Counter({'Failed': 2, 'Succeeded': 3})
```

---

**General Tip**

Dictionaries with consecutive integer keys are a waste of memory. You could just use a list

```
my_list = ['Succeeded', 'Succeeded', 'Failed', 'Failed', 'Succeeded']
```

into which you can index with integers `0, 1, 2, ...` like you would with your original dictionary. The list takes less memory and values can be found without hashing keys.

In this case, `Counter(my_list)` would construct the dictionary you desire.

---

**WARNING BAD CODE BELOW**

You *could* but **not** *should* write a comprehension as follows

```
>>> vals = list(d.values())
>>> {v:vals.count(v) for v in vals}
{'Failed': 2, 'Succeeded': 3}
```

but I strongly advise against using this comprehension because as opposed to the O(n) `Counter` solution, it has quadratic time complexity. For each value in `vals`, `vals` is iterated in order to count the value.

Comment: Thanks @timgeb
Yes with an additional package I am able to do it.
But without using any external package will it be possible? I am not able to frame the logic.

Comment: @ArijitGhosh no problem. `collections.Counter` is part of the standard library, so there's not really a reason not to use it.